# Ingest data from JDBC connections to Hive : Handling binary columns

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, hdfs, ocr

Following diagram depicts the simplified ingestion flow we are building to ingest data from different RDBS to Hive.

**Step 1**: Using JDBC connection to the data-source, source data is streamed and saved in a CSV file on HDFS using HDFS java API.
        Basically, execute a 'SELECT * ' query and each row is saved in CSV until the ResultSet is exhausted.

**Step 2**: Using LOAD DATA INPATH command, Hive table is populated using the CSV file created in Step 1.

We use JDBC ResultSet.getString() to get column data.
This works fine for non-binary data.

But for BLOC,CLOB type columns, we cannot write column data into a text/CSV file.

My question is it possible to use OCR or AVRO format to handle binary columns? Does these formats support write row-by-row?

(Update: We are aware of Sqoop/Nifi..etc technologies, the reason for implementing our custom ingestion-flow is beyond the scope of this question)

[image]

Comment: It is possible. Read this about ORC: https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html But storing big binary values inside ORC with other columns is too much overhead. If binary values are big, consider storing them in separate files and URI in the ORC, this will improve ORC compression and performance.

Comment: @leftjoin so I can directly read bytes using ResultSet.getBytes(int column) and save in a ORC binary column?

Comment: You can. More useful links on ORC :https://codecheese.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/writing-an-orc-file-using-java/ and https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile